# Deleting list from list of list if they have the matching value in the fixed index of the list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to delete the lists from the list of list,

I am trying to search for the particularly 1st index and 3rd index from the list

checking for the next list in that if the same value exists in the 1st index and  3rd index

I want to delete that list from the full list

only one list should exist 1st  and 3rd value-combining ly should be unique throughout the list

the output which I am getting

```
[['C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023012_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_1', 233, 'auto-labeled'],
['C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022956_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_2', 48, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023054_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_3', 235, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023056_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_4', 267, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022978_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_5', 59, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023007_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_11', 52, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022956_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_6', 39, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022963_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_6', 39, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022964_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_6', 39, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022965_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_6', 39, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022967_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_6', 39, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022956_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_7', 39, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023061_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_39', 49, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023064_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_39', 49, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022963_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_8', 42, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023004_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_8', 42, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023009_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_8', 42, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023005_c0.png', 'Rider_14', 647, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023059_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_18', 314, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022999_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_21', 46, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023004_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_21', 46, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023072_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_20', 122, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023044_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_22', 75, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023052_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_25', 56, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023044_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_24', 76, 'Manual'],]
```

The expected output is :

```
[['C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023012_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_1', 233, 'auto-labeled'],
['C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022956_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_2', 48, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023054_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_3', 235, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023056_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_4', 267, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022978_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_5', 59, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023007_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_11', 52, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022956_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_6', 39, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022956_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_7', 39, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023061_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_39', 49, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022963_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_8', 42, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023005_c0.png', 'Rider_14', 647, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023059_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_18', 314, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022999_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_21', 46, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023072_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_20', 122, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023044_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_22', 75, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023052_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_25', 56, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023044_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_24', 76, 'Manual'],]
```

please, someone, suggest me the code to achieve the required output

Thanks in advance

Comment: It should be a simple dict comprehension ```{path[2] : path for path in paths}.values()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `set` stores unique values. According to the question, the first and third element must be unique together. So we use them as a key in the set. After that we `filter` and remove any element that is already present in the set.

```
s = set()
new_list = list(filter(lambda x: any([(x[0], x[2]) not in s, s.add((x[0], x[2]))]), old_list))
print(new_list)

#Output
[['C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023012_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_1', 233, 'auto-labeled'],
['C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022956_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_2', 48, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023054_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_3', 235, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023056_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_4', 267, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022978_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_5', 59, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023007_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_11', 52, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022956_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_6', 39, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022956_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_7', 39, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023061_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_39', 49, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022963_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_8', 42, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023005_c0.png', 'Rider_14', 647, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023059_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_18', 314, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022999_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_21', 46, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023072_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_20', 122, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023044_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_22', 75, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023052_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_25', 56, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023044_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_24', 76, 'Manual'],]
```

Answer (score 0):

As actually say [Sushanth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62276042/deleting-list-from-list-of-list-if-they-have-the-matching-value-in-the-fixed-ind#comment110140265_62276042), dict comprehension can help you. But with some correct:

```
list({path[2] : path for path in paths[::-1]}.values())[::-1]
```

because we want to save first repeated element from list.

Then we have following result:

```
[['C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023012_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_1', 233, 'auto-labeled'],
['C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022956_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_2', 48, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023054_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_3', 235, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023056_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_4', 267, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022978_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_5', 59, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023007_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_11', 52, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022956_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_6', 39, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022956_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_7', 39, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023061_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_39', 49, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022963_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_8', 42, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023005_c0.png', 'Rider_14', 647, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023059_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_18', 314, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000022999_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_21', 46, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023072_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_20', 122, 'auto-labeled'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023044_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_22', 75, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023052_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_25', 56, 'Manual'],
[ 'C:\\Users\\101', 'img_000023044_c0.png', 'Pedestrian_24', 76, 'Manual'],]
```